# Efficient approximation to integration of analytic expressions involving product of four bessel functions

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have to take many integrals of the form

$$
\int_0^\infty \!dx\,\,e^{-x}\,x^{\gamma - 2\beta - 2\alpha} j_\alpha ( u_1 x)j_\alpha (u_2 x)j_{\beta}(u_3 x)j_\beta (u_4 x),$$

where $\gamma$ is an integer. Note that the power $\gamma -2\alpha - 2\beta$ is such that the integrand is an analytic function over the entire complex plane. The parameters regime I am interested  is a fairly dense sampling of the region $1 \lesssim u_i \lesssim 100$, for a small number of different choices of $\gamma$, $\beta$ and $\alpha$ which are of order one.

I understand the asymptotic behavior of this integral, which has singular behavior whenever a signed sum of the $u$ is zero. Unfortunately, it seems like I need something on the order of 1% precision for my intended application, and attempting to patch together the asymptotic behavior is not sufficient.

Mathematica is able to numerically evaluate this integral relatively quickly, especially for small $u$. However it slows as $u$ increase (to be expected for an oscillatory integral), and even at relatively fast speeds the number of integrals makes it quite prohibitive.

**Q:Could make a suggestion for a transformation of this integral that would lead to a more numerically tractable problem? Any leads or ideas would be appreciated.**

To give a flavor of what I am hoping for one might try to expand the integrand in series like

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{\gamma-2\alpha -2\beta}\sum_{n ,\vec{a}} F^n_{a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4} x^n u_1^{a_1} u_2^{a_2} u_3 ^{a_3} u_4^{a_4} $$

Swap the sum and integral (if it were convergent)

$$\sum_{\vec{a}} u_1^{a_1} u_2^{a_2} u_3 ^{a_3} u_4^{a_4} \sum_n \Gamma(\gamma-2\alpha -2\beta +n -1) F^n_{a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4}$$

We could then precompute the coefficients $\sum_n \Gamma(\gamma-2\alpha -2\beta +n -1) F^n_{a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4}$ up to whatever high order we wished for a given $\alpha, \beta ,\gamma$. Then calculating the integral could be done for a dense sampling by just plugging calculating the series for a given value of the $u$.

This doesnt work at all, which is not surprising as the integrand is very poorly modelled by a polynomial and in fact the resulting is not even convergent. So some other  idea would be greatly appreciated. I know there exist specialized expansions for Bessel functions and even products of Bessel functions, but I would no know how to go about solving this particular problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Just clarifying, which Bessel functions are you using, the ones of integer order ($J_n(x)$) or the ones of half-integer order ($j_n(x) = \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2x}J_{n+1/2}(x)$)?

Comment: Have you tried [Generalized Gauss-Laguerre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature)? That might work. You will need separate rules for every value of $\gamma - 2 \alpha - 2 \beta$. Also you might get better results if $x^\delta$ is taken from $j_\alpha(x)$ at $x = 0$, e.g. $j_\alpha(x) = x^\alpha f_\alpha(x)$

Comment: @uranix: thanj you so much! I meant the usual Bessel function, but since I'm actually interested in non-integer $alpha$ and $beta$ it doesn't matter which nd you choose. Thank you for suggesting the quadrature method, I will try it. Do you have any sense of when this quadrature method works well? Because the Integrand is not smooth on the scale order one I am worried the convergence will be poor.

Comment: I actually tried, but the error is large for $u_i \sim 10$. Can you please give me some test cases? I also wonder if this integral can be evaluated in frequency (Fourier) domain, like [Borwein integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral)

Comment: @uranix: I do not think that laguerre quadrature will be useful, because the difficulty is not sampling the exponential tail, but avergaing the highly oscillatory part for x of order one. So I'm attempting to use oscillatory methods like the Levin transformation. As for test cases, $\alpha = 1$, $\beta = 1/4$, $\gamma = 0$ and the $u_i$ around 10 is the kind of thing I am interested in. As for fourier space, it is true the bessel functions have compact support in fourier space, but you may end up with mutli-dimensional integral with singularities if you do it this way.